# cdb/windbg output too large

Tags: windbg, windows-error-reporting

We are using cdb (command line version of winDBG) to resolve a cab.
For getting the output in a file we are using the -logo output to specify the output file.
For a certain cab we are getting "**CvRegToMachine(x86) conversion failure for 0x7536**" more than a million times.
Basically we get a huge resolved code log, nearly 1GB, and all of it filled with the above string on each line.
We are using the following cdb command
**cdb -z "abc.cab" -y "SymbolsPath" -G -logo "outputfile" -lines -c ".kframes 100;!analyze -v;!load msec.dll;!exploitable -v;vertarget;lmv;q"**
Does anyone have any clue about what could be wrong here?

Comment: Have you verified that you are using the correct version of cdb for the processor architecture the dump file is from?

Comment: yes. it is working fine for other cabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you `cannot use -c and -G at the same time` -c needs the first break to read the initial
command and act upon it if you need to run the code use g; at the end of -c commands

also many times `-c commands need to be provided first` and the debugee needs
to be at the end of commandline

```
cdb -c "<some cmd;someother cmd;g>" -z foo.cab
```

`.load` not `!load` should be used to load third party extensions

the string emitted `"CvReg.........."` seems to be related to Either `SYMFLAG_NULL` or `SYMFLAG_REGISTER` in the `Flags member of SYMBOLINFO Struct` .

a sample trial didnt cross that code path in my machine so either the corrupt dmp or more information regarding the dmp file may be needed to find the reason for the spew

**creating dump**

```
C:\>dir /b *.cab
File Not Found

C:\>cdb -c ".dump /ma /b foo.cab;q" calc | grep -i -E "dmp|dump|wr"
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.dump /ma /b foo.cab;q'
Creating C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\foo.cab.dmp - mini user dump
Dump successfully written
  Adding C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\foo.cab.dmp - added
Wrote foo.cab

C:\>dir /b *.cab
foo.cab
```

**loading dump as debugees(cdb) debuggee (foo.cab) and looking around **

```
C:\>cdb cdb -z foo.cab

    0:000> s -u dbgeng l?39b000  "CvReg"
020341f8  0043 0076 0052 0065 0067 0054 006f 004d  C.v.R.e.g.T.o.M.

0:000> # *(*20341f8 dbgeng l?39b000
dbgeng!MachineInfo::CvRegToMachine+0xfe:
021bf8ae 68f8410302      push    offset dbgeng!`string' (020341f8)

0:000> # call*dbgeng!MachineInfo::CvRegToMachine dbgeng l?39b000
dbgeng!ImageInfo::CvRegToMachine+0x22:
021b62f2 e8b9940000      call    dbgeng!MachineInfo::CvRegToMachine (021bf7b0)

0:000> # call*CvRegToMachine dbgeng l?39b000
dbgeng!ImageInfo::CvRegToMachine+0x22:
021b62f2 e8b9940000      call    dbgeng!MachineInfo::CvRegToMachine (021bf7b0)
dbgeng!TypeInfoValueFromSymInfo+0x4b:
022541ab e82021f6ff      call    dbgeng!ImageInfo::CvRegToMachine (021b62d0)
dbgeng!TypedData::SetToSymbol+0x25f:
02285edf e8ec03f3ff      call    dbgeng!ImageInfo::CvRegToMachine (021b62d0)
dbgeng!TypedData::SetToSymbol+0x2da:
02285f5a e87103f3ff      call    dbgeng!ImageInfo::CvRegToMachine (021b62d0)
0:000> ln 0x21bf8ae


(021bf7b0)   dbgeng!MachineInfo::CvRegToMachine+0xfe   |  (021bf8d0)   dbgeng!Ma
chineInfo::GetContextState
```

doing and uf on this function yields the check where SymbolInfo->Flags is
checked and    decided  my sample dump above doesnt enter the path

Comment: Thanks @blabb . I would take it that the cab being processed is corrupt. But I was wondering what would cause the processing to end if it was some kind of an endless loop caused by SYMFLAG_NULL. I forgot to mention, I am getting different sizes for different corrupted cabs and also, I am not getting out of memory while processing.